# Argument error decompresing zip file using shell

Tags: c#, com, compression, zip, windows-shell

I need to unzip a file that is located in base directory, for example, sample.zip. I have made A sample application for doing so. I have 1 input parameter - destination directory. Here are code samples:

```
private void BInstall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string currentdir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();//Gets current directory
    string zip = currentdir + "\\" + "sample.zip";//Path to zip file
    string outPath = TBoutputPath.Text;
    exctract(zip ,outPath );
}
```

And here is the function that is supposed to extract the zip file:

```
void exctract(string name, string path)
{
    string[] args = new string[2];
    if (name.IndexOf(" ") != -1)
    {
        //we got a space in the path so wrap it in double qoutes
        args[0] += "\"" + name + "\"";
    }
    else
    {
        args[0] += name;
    }

    if (path.IndexOf(" ") != -1)
    {
        //we got a space in the path so wrap it in double qoutes
        args[1] += " " + "\"" + path + "\"";
    }
    else
    {
        args[1] +=path;
    }

    Shell32.Shell sc = new Shell32.Shell(); 
    Shell32.Folder SrcFlder = sc.NameSpace(args[0]);
    Shell32.Folder DestFlder = sc.NameSpace(args[1]);
    Shell32.FolderItems items = SrcFlder.Items();
    DestFlder.CopyHere(items , 20); 
}
```

At `DestFlder.CopyHere(items , 20);` I get NullReferenceException, and I don't know why, since the objects shouldn't be null. It is DestFlder that is null; it seems that SrcFolder is initialized but  DestFlder is not. The only difference I can find is that DestFlder doesn't have a file extension following, but since it is a folder, it shouldn't have one anyway.

Can anyone explain me what I did wrong and how to fix that?

Comment: Can you use your debugger to work out which object (DestFlder, items) is null, if any? And whilst making the shell do this for you is an interesting problem, it might be simplest to use an unzip library e.g. SharpZipLib

Comment: The DestFlder shows as null and gives me "No further information on this object could be discovered" error report. Well 20 is an int, so this one should be a problem :D

Comment: look at your code where you have += "\"  + "\\" is defined in the string zip = currentdir + "\\" + "sample.zip";//Path to zip file perhaps you are appending an additional "\" debug and make sure that what you are looking for is located in the following string currentdir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();//Gets current directory
            string zip = currentdir + "\\" + "sample.zip";//Path to zip file perhaps you have some Path issues..

Comment: I checked. It doesn't seam to be the problem. It seams that SrcFolder is initiated but he DestFlder is not, only difference I can find is that DestFlder doesnt have a file extension fallowing, but since it is a folder, it shouldn't have one anyway.

Comment: Do the examples you're testing have a space in the name? Why do you add a leading space to the arg[1]-with-space case?

Comment: No. But I already found the cause of my error. The pointed folder did not exist. I will answer this myself or anyone else can do this, since I cant do that for another 7 hours. Thanks thou for pointing me to some other possible issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this problem was rather... trivial, but as all of the simplest problems, next to impossible to think of.

The folder did not exist and therefor could not be referenced to. This code piece fixed that:

```
        if (!Directory.Exists(args[1]))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(args[1]);
```

Thou DJ KRAZE did point to another problem with the script that could have it possibly get a run-time error eventually. Thank you for that!